# curl request to aws lambda runtime interface emulator times out

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I am new to aws and golang. I have written an aws lambda funciton in golang as follow

```
func Handler() (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    response := events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: 200,
        Body:"Hello World",}
log.Print(response.Body)
return response, nil
}
func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)}
```

Then I run this command to run aws lambda runtime interface

```
~/.aws-lambda-rie/aws-lambda-rie go run main.go
```

then from a seperate shell I send following curl command

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:8080/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations
```

the log I get on my server is as follow

```
    03 Nov 2023 20:36:11,401 [INFO] (rapid) exec 'go' (cwd=/home/sannanyousaf/Desktop/Oviproxy, handler=main.go)
    03 Nov 2023 20:36:27,184 [INFO] (rapid) extensionsDisabledByLayer(/opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j) -> stat /opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j: no such file or directory
    START RequestId: dcef5a34-a41d-49b2-bb50-09cac8868b82 Version: $LATEST
    03 Nov 2023 20:36:27,184 [INFO] (rapid) Configuring and starting Operator Domain
    03 Nov 2023 20:36:27,184 [INFO] (rapid) Starting runtime domain
    03 Nov 2023 20:36:27,184 [WARNING] (rapid) Cannot list external agents error=open /opt/extensions: no such file or directory
    03 Nov 2023 20:36:27,185 [INFO] (rapid) Starting runtime without AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN , Expected?: false
```

and the curl request times out. Can any one point out what am I doing wrong, is there a problem with my setup or have I done something wrong while writing the code?

Comment: I can't see your `docker run` command but try `localhost:9000` instead.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary doesnt work, gives "refused to connect message" and the server doesnt show any logs

Comment: How are you running RIE?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I tried to read the official RIE documentation. It was suggesting three methods. I could not decide which one to use. I am not sure that if it is a matter of choice or it is something dependant on your setup. I tried to ask chat gpt and it suggested the above method. Can you guide me through? Also I know very little about dockerfiles and how to write one. Can you suggest me a good read on that